# Hibernate: ERROR- column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to change the SQL query to CriteriaBuilder way and facing this error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: column "lopcoverag0_.slot" must appear in the GROUP BY clause 
or be used in an aggregate function
```

**SQL** - This query works for me when I do in the SQLWorkbench

```
select count(*) from (Select distinct slot from lop_coverage 
where pageFamily='Gateway' and currentStatus ='Active' 
and (lop in ("[en_US]","none")) group by creativeID) as totalcount;
```

To **JPA CriteriaBuilder**:

```
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<String> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(String.class);
        Root<LOPCoverage> root = criteriaQuery.from(LOPCoverage.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root.get(LOPCoverage_.slot)).distinct(true);

        List<String> lopList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"none", "[en_US]"});

        Expression<String> lopExpression = root.get(LOPCoverage_.lop);
        Predicate lopINPredicate = lopExpression.in(lopList);

        Predicate andRestriction = criteriaBuilder.and(
                criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("pageFamily"), pageFamily),
                lopINPredicate);


        criteriaQuery.where(andRestriction).groupBy(root.get("creativeID"));

        System.out.println( session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).list());
```

**from hibernate logs this is the query generated**

```
Hibernate: select distinct lopcoverag0_.slot as col_0_0_ from 
lop_coverage lopcoverag0_ where lopcoverag0_.page_family=? and 
(lopcoverag0_.lop in (? , ?)) group by lopcoverag0_.creative_id
```

I understood there is a mistake in my code in criteriaBuilder can someone tell me issue or point me to right place

Comment: The first query you show also doesn't work unless creativeID is a primary key.  Since you are now querying a different table with different columns, maybe it is no longer a primary key.

Comment: Yes. tables are different. Initially the code in the package was written using JDBC and plain SQL strings and DB is mysql. Now I'm refactoring the whole code to use hibernate and postgresql.

Comment: @jjanes I updated the queries. please check

Answer (score 1):

> Select distinct slot

this is not a aggregate function nor is it in the group by

either
`select distinct group, slot`
or `select group, slot ... group by group, slot`

Comment: Just checked this query is working with SQL DB:
```select count(*) from (Select distinct slot from lop_coverage where page_family='Consumables' 
and current_status ='Active' and (lop in ('en_IN','none')) group by creative_id) as totalcount```.  but not in postgresql DB

Comment: I modified this query to 
```select count(*) from (Select distinct creative_id, slot from lop_coverage where execution_date='2020-07-02' and page_family='Consumables' 
and current_status ='Active' and (lop in ('en_IN]','none')) group by creative_id, slot) as totalcount```

It is not showing error but the slot values are duplicated

Comment: if you just want the distinct slots - just select distinct slots without any grouping

Comment: need distinct slot count with grouping. As creative ids are duplicated